# Horizontal empty body overflow

Tags: css, html

On http://zhuortho.tk there is a scroll bar on the x-axis if the window gets too narrow, but if you scroll to the right when it appears, there's absolutely nothing there. I've checked all the paddings and margins, nothing seems to be out of order. This is what it looks like. http://i.imgur.com/Y7Ttf82.jpg?1 The white space is completely empty, the gray footer at the bottom is fixed and is not causing it.

I've found the cause to be the "Contact Us" section at the bottom of the page, but I don't know how to fix it. Removing the "Phone" div fixes the problem but obviously breaks the rest.

I don't see what is causing the problem, is it something with the phone div? It doesn't happen with the other large divs.

Can I fix it with a couple of quick css changes? Do I have to use a table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `.pcontainer` element has a width of `860px`. Remove it.

```
.pcontainer {
position: absolute;
width: 860px;
height: auto;
margin: 20px;
}
```